# Is this possible with calculated column?

Tags: calculated-column

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a column with this 2014-*NNNN*/XXT

I need to extact the number part (NNNN) and increment with nearest multiple of 10. So for instance if the number is 5010, the result should 5020. **But** if the number is 5016 the result should also be 5020.

Up until now, I have only be able able to extract the number by using 2 calculated columns: one with the RIGHT function in order to remove **2014-** and the LEFT function acting on result to remove **/xxt**.

I now need to increment with a multiple of 10, as previously explained.

Any assistance would very appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: just to clarify. 5019 = 5020; 5090 = 5100; 5101 = 5110 ?

Comment: that is correct. @MdMazzotti

Comment: will NNNN always be 4 characters?

Comment: Yes, and it will always be a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your formula:

=VALUE(MID([YourField];6;4))-MOD(VALUE(MID([YourField];6;4));10)+10

(no need to have 2 calculated columns; only one will do)

Comment: YourField in this case would be the column with 2014-NNNN/XXT ? is this correct?

Comment: @LuisCarvalho yes, correct

Comment: IT is working!! there was just a little typo on your text - a [ was missing just before second instance of YourField.
YOU ARE THE BEST!!!

Comment: glad it helped :) (edited my answer to fix the typo)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of manipulation of dates, I prefer using JavaScript.

Check this library of JQuery [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). This library helps me a lot when it comes to manipulating dates.

You can do what you want in PreSaveAction SharePoint function [example](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/86fe14fc-f353-4521-bf88-fd7fcabaa768/using-presaveaction-in-newformaspx-in-sharepoint-list).

Comment: Can you please explain how would you do it in this case? I have no knowledge of javacsript. thanks. @diego hillesheim

Comment: You have to sum ​​multiple of 10 or it may be that also subtract?